# po2xliff conversion in windows

Tags: windows, localization, po

Can anyone help in using the command po2xliff([http://web.iesrodeira.com/cgi-bin/man/man2html?query=install+po2xliff](http://web.iesrodeira.com/cgi-bin/man/man2html?query=install%20po2xliff)) in windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download Translate Toolkit-1.9.0-setup.exe from http://sourceforge.net/projects/translate/files/Translate%20Toolkit/1.9.0/Translate%20Toolkit-1.9.0-setup.exe/download and install.

**Command Usage:** *po2xliff pofilename xlifffilename*

Where,

```
<po> is a PO file
<tmx> is an XLIFF file
```

**Example**: *po2xliff C:\Po\fra.po C:\Xliff\fr.xliff*